# Is there any better way to carry out partial match of a vector of strings in c++?

Tags: c++, optimization

I have two vectors of strings and want to carry out a partial/full match between each string i.e

```
std::vector<std::string> A = { "AA", "ABC" }
std::vector<std::string> B = { "AABB", "AABC", "ABC", "BC"}
```

I want to perform a partial/full match for all strings in A with all strings in B.
Simplest approach would be just run loops over both vectors

```
for(const string& s1 : A)
{
  for(const string& s2 : B)
  {
    if(s2.find(s1) != std::string::npos)
      std::cout << "partial matched" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Results for the above example would be:

```
"AA"  --> "AABB", "AABC"
"ABC" --> "AABC", "ABC"
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Just to find if there are matches?

Comment: Do you want to return `true` if ANY of the elements of `B` exist in `A`? Or do you need to know the full set of `string`s in `B` that are also in `A`?

Comment: Are the vectors sorted at all? Are you allowed to sort them?

Comment: I am trying to find if a string in A 'partially matches' with a string in B.

Comment: I can sort the vectors if that helps in optimizing

Comment: Searching whether a string from one set is included in a string from the other set offers few optimization paths if any... In the general case, brute force (compare each string from A to each string from B) should be the way to go. If the sets are huge you could try to pre-process them by testing if a string from one (sub-) set in included in an other string from the same (sub-) set. The rationale is kind of a divide and conquer. As the algo is quadratic reducing the size can be interesting. But it should only be worth it you reduce the size by a magnitude order.

Comment: IMHO: Since the only operations here are insert and retrieval with equal suffixes, a Trie would be an advisable solution. And to save memory, also the variant using a `std::unordered_map` in the Trie could be used.

Answer (score 2):

The brute force method is by far the simplest. You can potentially make the code cleaner by using nested calls to `std::any_of`.

To be more efficient, you need to wade deep into complex string searching algorithms. I believe the state of the art in multiple-pattern search is [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm). A variant is [Commentz-Walter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commentz-Walter_algorithm).

There's a BSD 2-clause (looks like)-licensed implementation of Aho-Corasick [on Github](https://github.com/cjgdev/aho_corasick/), though you'd probably want to add a modified main searching function to immediately return if any match is found, instead of collecting all.

If you really want to wade deep into the reeds, you could start with [this paper](http://www.iajit.org/PDF/November%202019,%20No.%206/15585.pdf) and follow the references.

Answer (score 1):

`std::set_intersection` might be what you want since you do not elaborate on the context.

Assumes the request is:

1. The match means "full string comparison".
2. Need to know the partial matched result.

The time complexity of `std::intersection` is at most `2*(a.size() + b.size())` while the brute force method is O(n^2).
[Reference here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)

Note: you might want to know the construction and insertion time of `std::set` as well.

Note 2: you may also use sorted `std::vector` which is cache friendly for `std::set_intersection`

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> a{"bar","foo"};
    std::set<std::string> b{"oof","foo","par"};
    std::vector<std::string> intersect;
    std::set_intersection(b.begin(),b.end(),
                        a.begin(),a.end(),
                        std::back_inserter(intersect));

    std::cout << intersect.size() << std::endl;
    for(std::string& matched: intersect){
        std::cout << matched << std::endl;    
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z4P5bfK76)

Comment: Note that a) set_intersection requires the two sequences to be sorted, and b) this only does full string comparison.

Comment: @SebastianRedl you can use any strict weak order on the strings you like, they just have to be sorted wrt that, which *might* map to the desired comparison

Comment: The OP's brute force code clearly is checking whether strings from A contain strings from B as substrings. There is no strict weak order that maps to this behavior.